# MySQL Error “Query was empty”

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

```
$send_event = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT `bmembMember` FROM `bmembBusiness` = '%u' WHERE `bmembBusiness` = '%u' ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC", $bs['busId'])) OR die('Cron not run') ;
while($se=$db->fetch_row($send_event))
{
$text = "The {$bs['busName']} business went bankrupt\, all members have been made redundent." OR die('Cron not run');
```

Thanks

Comment: It's worth looking into using prepared statements and bind variables and you should also check for failures (`$send_event` may be false if the query fails)

Comment: Using `sprintf` does not at all secure your database from SQL injection.  Look into what NigelRen has mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Your sprintf uses 2 values, but you only provide one.  One isn't needed anyway and that line should be

```
$send_event = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT `bmembMember` FROM `bmembBusiness` WHERE `bmembBusiness` = '%u' ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC", $bs['busId'])) OR die('Cron not run') ;
```

Comment: "*one isn't needed*" is slightly inaccurate - it shouldn't be there *at all*, as you can't use `FROM table = 'something'`, it's simply `FROM table`.

Comment: 'Slightly inaccurate' !!

Comment: thanks for the reply when i use that i get 500 server error

Comment: and when i do it like this $send_event = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT `bmembMember` FROM  WHERE `bmembBusiness` = '%u' ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC", $bs['busId'])) OR die('Cron not run') ;      then i get ........QUERY ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `bmembBusiness` = '3' ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC' at line 1
Query was SELECT `bmembMember` FROM WHERE `bmembBusiness` = '3' ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC

Comment: Your missing the table name in this SQL - FROM WHERE is missing something in the middle.

Comment: when i do the table name in there it results on http 500 error

Comment: Have you run this statement in something like phpmyadmin?  Do you know what error your getting and where?  It may be unrelated to this SQL as it's obviously getting past this bit when you have a table name.

Comment: it works in phpmyadmin ans when i run the cron it seems to update even when i run it in browser it gives 500 error   so i think it works but time will tell thank you

Answer (score 1):

Fix the `FROM` Clause which should fix the query.

```
 ...FROM `bmembBusiness` WHERE...
```

Answer (score -1):

Highted area of query is wrong,

"SELECT `bmembMember` **FROM `bmembBusiness` = '%u'** WHERE `bmembBusiness` = '%u' ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC", $bs['busId'])

**Try This Which should Fix the query** :-

> SELECT `bmembMember` FROM **Table_name** WHERE `bmembBusiness` **Like** '%u'
>   ORDER BY `bmembId` DESC, abs(busId);

Comment: Using `Like` instead of `=` changes the logic of the query. The reason the `%` is there is not for SQL but for `sprintf`